# Finding an item by object value in Combobox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a combo box that is populated with an Arraylist, like below. If I have another instance of same object, how do I select that object in the combobox? Please look at the code below to understand.

```
        MakeEntity selectedMake = Make.GetMakeByTitle("Honda");
        List<MakeEntity> allMakes = Make.GetAllMakes();
        cbVehicleMake.DataSource = allMakes;
        cbVehicleMake.SelectedIndex = cbVehicleMake.Items.IndexOf(selectedMake);
```

But last line is not working as expected. Can I get it to run at all or am I going in the wrong direction? Should MakeEntity implement iComparable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming MakeEntity has an property called id!

```
 cbVehicleMake.SeletedItem=allMakes.Find(q=>q.Id==selectedMake.Id))
```

Comment: Short, Crisp & Sweet... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to implement `IComparable` for `IndexOf`, just `Equals`. Otherwise it will default to `Object.Equals`, which only matches if the two references are to the same instance. (Not sure if this is a problem or not without seeing the definition of `MakeEntity`.)

Also, just use:

```
cbVehicleMake.SelectedItem = selectedMake;
```

This will internally handle finding the object in the options.

Documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem.aspx

Comment: It doesnt work. Reason could be `selectedMake` is a different object than the one present in `allMakes`. Should I rather override the `equals` method?

Comment: Yes. Override the Equals method so that two different instances of the MakeEntity will be considered 'equal' if their identifying properties are equal. Looking at your code, the Title might be a good candidate.